# Suggest tool to convert cpp code to UML class diagram

Tags: c++, linux, uml

I want to propose some class interface changes in my project. I feel that changes would be best explained using UML class diagrams.

My project code base is in C++ (RHEL).

Could you please tell me any open source/free tool that works on linux (ubuntu gnome - so preferably gtk app) and can help me to generate the class diagrams given the class declaration for the same.

Thanks,
Amey

Comment: see similar / same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407948/c-to-uml-reverse-engineer-round-trip-engineering)

Comment: similar here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232666/free-uml-tools-for-c  Consider if you me generate or just manually create.  Changes the question quite a bit.

Answer (score 2):

As I know Umbrello supports reverse engineering for C++

Comment: Its qt app, I guess. I will need to download 65MB to install this app. Its too heavy for me

Answer (score 1):

You can use doxygen:

http://www.doxygen.org

This is not exactly UML but doxygen let you: *"visualize the relations between the various elements by means of include dependency graphs, inheritance diagrams, and collaboration diagrams, which are all generated automatically."* This is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Dia before. With it you can create many different kinds of diagrams in addition to UML modelling. 
Check the [Dia Homepage](http://live.gnome.org/Dia). Take a look at examples and demo.
And yes it is open source and GTK+ based.

This demo is close to what you may want to do.
[image]